# Node framework with postgres schema support for multi-tenant applications?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, multi-tenant

I'm trying to build a multi-tenant API app and am looking to segregate tenant data into schemas in postgres, however, I can't find any nodejs framework that has an ORM that explicitly supports schemas in postgres. The closest thing I've found to it is the Bookshelf ORM which supports passing in options for SQL query construction, but this seems a bit hacky. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're going out of your way to separate the databases, might I suggest separating out the application instances as well?  To do this correctly, regardless of ORM, you will need a separate connection for each database.  There is a lot of overhead to that, depending on what scale you intend to operate at.  But, if you are concerned about security, why not split your API so you have separate application instances for each?  You can switch between them with a proxy out front, like Nginx.

Comment: I want to split it out for security and concern over how large the tables might be, so this sounds pretty good. How exactly would you seperate out the app instances?

Comment: The specifics of that are going to depend on your application.  Generally speaking, you'll need some sort of supervisor process that you write which spawns processes for each customer, starting them up automatically, handling restarts for new versions, etc.  You'll need some sort of centralized config management, which could be as simple as a JSON file on disk, but more than likely an API for which your supervisor to talk to.  You'll need some sort of edge routing, which is easily implemented as a proxy which points to the application servers for each instance.

Comment: @LewisVatcky you can support an SQL schema on your own side, if you execute queries directly, without using any ORM. Check out [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

Comment: @vitaly-t, I think that's the best way to go now. Unfortunate that I have to gove up the ORM, but it would mean I have more control over it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a complete article about How i implement that

[How i create multi-tenant SaaS product using Node + Sequelize + Postgres](https://medium.com/@mohamedsameer72/how-we-build-the-multi-tenant-saas-product-using-node-postgres-sequelize-c66a085a42ce)